# Angular Ionic Cordova - Default Image Source Directive

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Using some combination of Angular / Ionic / Cordova how can I dynamically set the image source to default if request image doesn't exist.  NOTE: I know this can be done with an OnError directive, however this results in a temporary question mark image which I would like to avoid. Perhaps making a Cordova File call?

```
<img ng-src="{{employee.id}}.jpg" df-img-src="default.jpg"/>
```

Taking things one step further, what about dealing with unknown file extensions. Say if the employee picture can end in either gif, png, jpg, or jpeg, and I would want to set the image-src to which ever one exists on the file system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this Directive.

```
app.directive('fallbackSrc', function () {
    return{
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('error', function () {
                angular.element(this).attr("src", attrs.fallbackSrc);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Usage:

```
<img ng-src="{{employee.id}}.jpg" fall-back-src="default.jpg"/>
```

Else create a directive for actual source like below

```
app.directive('actualSrc', function () {
    return{
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('actualSrc', function(newVal, oldVal){
                 if(newVal != undefined){
                     var img = new Image();
                     img.src = attrs.actualSrc;
                     angular.element(img).bind('load', function () {
                         element.attr("src", attrs.actualSrc);
                     });
                 }
            });

        }
    }
});
```

Usage:

```
<img actual-src="{{employee.id}}.jpg" ng-src="default.jpg"/>
```

[Pluker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pXSsXtGbRIjEyHGewUDo?p=preview)

Comment: This is what I tried .. However it causes a "?" image before default gets loaded. I was wondering if their is a way to avoid this, i.e. only ever request the correct image.

Comment: Better .. but it seems like the directive is getting called (and failing) before the {{employee.id}} gets injected. Consequently the default image still shows up.   Things work correctly if I hard code the employee number.

Comment: Beautiful! Worked like a charm, very slick.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just making a few improvements in [@Subash Selvaraj's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041468/angular-ionic-cordova-default-image-source-directive#26042673) to double check errors and guarantee the default image will be loaded in all kind of errors.

```
(function (Directives) {
    Directives.directive('fallbackSrc', function () {
        return {
            link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
                element.bind('error', function () {
                    angular.element(this).attr("src", attrs.fallbackSrc);
                });
            }
        }
    });

    Directives.directive('actualSrc', function () {
        return {
            link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
                attrs.$observe('actualSrc', function (newVal, oldVal) {
                    if (newVal != undefined) {
                        var img = new Image();
                        img.src = attrs.actualSrc;
                        angular.element(img).bind('load', function () {
                            element.attr("src", attrs.actualSrc);
                        });

                        angular.element(img).bind('error', function () {
                            element.attr("src", attrs.fallbackSrc);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }); 
})(Directives);
```

```
<img fall-back-src="img/PerfilPadrao.png" actual-src="{{UrlPhoto}}">
```